# Python Tkinter: Text widget unbind mouse wheel

Tags: python, events, text, tkinter, mousewheel

I currently have a GUI that uses the Text widget, and I realize mouse wheel can be used to scroll up and down the Text widget.

However, I already have a scroll bar for that task, and I am planning to use mouse wheel for other tasks. So how do you unbind this event from Text widget?

Example code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def onclick():
   pass

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, "Hello.....")
for _ in range(1000):
   text.insert(END, "Bye Bye.....")
text.pack()

text.tag_add("here", "1.0", "1.4")
text.tag_add("start", "1.8", "1.13")
text.tag_config("here", background="yellow", foreground="blue")
text.tag_config("start", background="black", foreground="green")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return 'break'` in the callback will override the default behavior. Just bind the `<MouseWheel>` event to the text widget:

```
def scrollwheel(event):
    return 'break'

text.bind('<MouseWheel>', scrollwheel)
```

Refer to: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Comment: Worked like a charm! I kept trying unbind but no luck, so thank you!

Comment: I have another problem regarding mouseover event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995932/python-tkinter-display-description-in-status-bar