# Balloon box with optionmenu in tkinter (python)

Tags: python, tkinter, tooltip, optionmenu

I am creating a GUI that contains a drop-down box (called an `optionmenu` in tkinter). I have it populated with entries.

This is what I want to do but can't figure out the proper commands. If a user hovers their mouse over a specific entry in the option menu, I want a hoverbox/balloon box/tooltip (whatever you want to call it) to appear and show a description of the option they are hovering over.

I assume I have to use some sort of event but I am not sure. Does anyone know how?

Comment: I have tried to find some more ways to do this but am still stuck. I thought I made headway by finding a similar thing in the menu widget of tkinter. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995932/python-tkinter-display-description-in-status-bar) is very similar to what I want to do where an event is called when a optionmenu item is hovered over and a tooltip is created but I can't find the appropriate event. I thought that <<MenuSelect>> would work with option menu but it doesn't seem to be that way.