# Python Tkinter - Virtual Event <<MenuSelect>> not working?

Tags: python, tkinter, events, menu, mouse

In my tkinter code, see below, I try to leverage the `<<MenuSelect>>` virtual event in order to print a simple message to the console.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Menu, N, W, E, S, DISABLED
from tkinter import ttk


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Contacts App')
        self.geometry('500x350')
        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(
            N, W, E, S), padx=10, pady=10)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.statusbar = StatusBar()
        self.statusbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(W, E))
        self.menubar = MenuBar()
        self.config(menu=self.menubar)


class MenuBar(Menu):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Start Menu
        self.menu_start = Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.menu_start.add_command(
            label="New Contact", command=self.create_contact, accelerator='Ctrl+C')
        self.menu_start.add_command(
            label="New Account", command=self.create_account, accelerator='Ctrl+A')
        self.menu_start.add_separator()
        self.menu_start.add_command(
            label="Settings", command=self.open_settings)
        self.menu_start.entryconfigure('Settings', state=DISABLED)
        self.menu_start.add_separator()
        self.menu_start.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit)
        self.add_cascade(menu=self.menu_start, label="Start")

        # Virtual Event not working
        self.menu_start.bind('<<MenuSelect>>', lambda event: print(
            f'Menu item {event.widget.index("active")}'))

    def create_contact(self):
        pass

    def create_account(self):
        pass

    def open_settings(self):
        pass


class StatusBar(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.status_label = ttk.Label(
            self, borderwidth=1, anchor='w', padding="0 0 3 0",
            relief='solid', background='#cbd2db', foreground='#302f35')
        self.status_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(W, E))

    def set(self, text):
        self.status_label['text'] = text
        self.status_label.update_idletasks()

    def clear(self):
        self.status_label['text'] = ''
        self.status_label.update_idletasks()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

In a next iteration I would like to show text information at the status bar when the user moves the mouse over menu items (similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995932/python-tkinter-display-description-in-status-bar). However, it seems that `<<MenuSelect>>` doesn't work at all. I don't see any console output. Any suggestions?

Comment: This link may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33132486/how-to-use-menuselect-to-bind-to-a-tkinter-menu-item-selection

Comment: Thanks @Derek, but it still doesn't work. I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.11.4. I also tried it on my brothers machine, which is running Linux/Python 3.11.4, without success.